# How do I select data from a table consisting of a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, User & Playlist

Table User:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(26) NOT Null UNIQUE,
    email TEXT NOT Null UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Table Playlist:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Playlist (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    image BLOB,
    private NUMERIC,
    playlistOwner VARCHAR(26),
    FOREIGN KEY(playlistOwner) REFERENCES User(id)
)
```

Playlist table:
[image]

What I have tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM Playlist
JOIN Playlist 
ON 10 = Playlist.playlistOwner
WHERE playlistOwner = ald;
```

Which gives the error:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of things that can be posted as text, especially error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want the column `playlistOwner` of the table `Playlist` as foreign key that references the column `id` of the table `User` you should define with the same data type as the referenced column.

So the correct definition should be `playlistOwner INTEGER`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Playlist (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    image BLOB,
    private NUMERIC,
    playlistOwner INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(playlistOwner) REFERENCES User(id)
)
```

and the values that you store in the column `playlistOwner` must be the `id`s of the users and not their `username`s.

Now if you know the user's `id` there is no need for a join.
You simply do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Playlist
WHERE playlistOwner = 10;
```

If you know only the `username` then you join the tables:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Playlist p INNER JOIN User u
ON u.id = p.playlistOwner 
WHERE u.username = 'somename'
```

or with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Playlist 
WHERE playlistOwner = (SELECT id FROM User WHERE username = 'somename')
```

Comment: Thank you @forpas, I only needed to change the datatype. Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you intend something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Playlist pl JOIN
     User u
     ON pl.playListOwner = u.id 
WHERE u.id = 10;
```

This is just a guess, but your question mentions two tables and the query references only one of them.  Plus, a self-join doesn't seem particularly useful.